# Install Solr Search Service failed - Sitecore 10

Tags: solr, sia

I am installing `Sitecore Experience Platform 10.1 Update-1` using a `Graphical setup package for XP Single`. After completion of pre-requisites when it install Solr Seach Service its failed and shows me the below message:

[image]

I have checked the log and in the log, I found below entries:
[image]

Can anyone please guide me what is the actual root cause behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is using just a space character in the `Windows service and path prefix` field in the `Install Solr search service` installation step in SIA:

[image: Windows Service and path prefix field]

You probably inserted a space to pass the validation on this section to enable the `Install` button, otherwise greyed out. The space is visible in the Solr service name in your error log as well.

If you still want to use SIA to install Solr (instead of manually installing it with SIF), you can avoid this issue using a prefix value that is not a space. You can also edit the `Solr.Service` variable defined in the `Solr-SingleDeveloper.json` configuration file distributed with your installation, removing in its value definition the concatenation of prefix and the solr service name:

```
"Solr.Service": "[concat(parameter('SolrServicePrefix'),variable('Solr.FileName'))]"
```

and instead using just the `Solr.FileName` variable:

```
"Solr.Service": "[variable('Solr.FileName')]"
```

Comment: Thanks, @alessandro.